# Husky pre-commit hook not ignoring node_modules

Tags: react-native, eslint, husky, lint-staged

I recently updated the dependencies on my React Native project, and we have `husky` pre-coomit hooks set up. I tried committing now and I get the following error:

```
myname@MacSelf014 my-project % git commit --amend
file:///<path-to-project>/node_modules/listr2/dist/index.js:206
    this.options.fields ??= {};
                        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:149:18)
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

The pre-commit set up looks like this in my `package.json`:

```
"lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write",
    ]
```

I've tried adding `node_modules` to `.husky/_/.gitignore` like so:

```
*
node_modules/*
```

And the problem persists. Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Why _would_ `.gitignore`-ing `node_modules/` in the `.husky` directory (where it isn't anyway) help? If you run the linting _without_ Husky does it exclude `node_modules/`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do have `node_modules` specified in the `.gitignore` in the root directory of my project, but that doesn't seem to be helping in this case. Yes, the linter ignores `node_modules` without Husky.

Comment: And have you [told ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/ignore#using-an-alternate-file) to use that? It's not in the command Husky is running. Give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't your linters, it's the listr2 package that husky uses to make nice console messages. It's probably your node version.

Check your node version in the terminal you used to make your commit with `node -v` and make sure yout have at least v16.

Sources :

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/listr2
- https://github.com/listr2/listr2/issues/689

Comment: Your answer does not resolve @Rameez Hussain 's problem. They want `husky` to ignore node_modules, not want to solve error of listr2 package

Answer (score 0):

i was having this issue while trying to commit directly from Rider or from Github client, but when i ran the commands from the terminal,
git add .
git commit -m '' it worked, so i would suggest you try that!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the `lint-staged` [README](https://github.com/lint-staged/lint-staged?tab=readme-ov-file#v13)

> Version v13.3.0 was incorrectly released including code of version v14.0.0. This means the breaking changes of v14 are also included in v13.3.0, the last v13 version released

v13.3.0 contains breaking changes of v14 and NodeJs v14 is not supported anymore. The error you see is related to this.

To fix the issue, you can either install a exact version of `lint-staged` that is prior to the issue

```bash
npm i --save-exact lint-staged@13.0.2
```

Or upgrade you NodeJs to v14.

---

Other Source: https://github.com/lint-staged/lint-staged/issues/1315